# When should a developer use doc1 over doc2 re: data table development in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, documentation

I'm curious why such rich documentation for data tables exists in two locations.
Are both intended for LWC developers? Why are there 2 doc endpoints about similar topics?

Doc1: [developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example)

Doc2: [lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLDS is a design system, like Google's Material, or BackboneJS, etc. It constitutes a guideline for what something would look like in a UI built on the system. You've probably seen SLDS on a number of sites without necessarily realizing it was SLDS. This includes developer guidelines for accessibility, styles, and so on, plus icons and CSS files you can download to use anywhere you want. You can use SLDS on your own website, in some blogs that allow custom code/CSS, and so on. SLDS can be used in React, Vue, Svelte, and more, without relying on LWC at all.

You've also probably have used LWC without realizing you were using LWC; SLDS and LWC are not tightly coupled outside of Salesforce. I have written a number of components that look very Salesforce-like, and I've written some local apps that you'd literally have to look at the source code to realize I was using LWC. Conceptually, you can adapt any style system, such as Material, to the LWC framework, though the Shadow DOM makes some of these transforms non-trivial. Want to use Tailwind with LWC? Nothing's stopping you from doing so.

Ultimately, the first documentation is about the implementation that exists inside Salesforce (including Lightning Experience and Digital Experiences), while the second documentation is about the way a data table should look and feel if conforming to SLDS. If you want to use LWC inside Salesforce, you will most likely want the first documentation. If you want to implement your own Salesforce-looking UI outside of Salesforce (including Canvas Apps, etc), the second will guide you on how to achieve that Salesforce look-and-feel in any framework you choose.

Of course, sometimes Salesforce's implementation limitations get in the way, in which case you might choose to implement the data table as a LWC. This requires a bit of work, but it can be done (I've done this at least once at this point); when the Salesforce version of a component isn't as robust as the SLDS blueprint it is based upon, you can always implement your own SLDS-based version in LWC to keep the Salesforce look-and-feel yet add your own personal flair.

Answer (score 3):

Doc2 explains how to construct the UI for a datatable type component using SLDS.

Doc1 tells you about the Salesforce datatable base component that you can use without writing any code.

You use info from Doc2 as the basis of writing your own datatable component, at least for the UI aspect, when the base component cannot be adapted to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I found a doc citing usefulness of both

paraphrased: "To change the styling of a base Lightning component, first check the Component Reference (component-library) to see whether the component has design variations. To change the spacing of a component, such as the alignment, padding, margin, or even its typography, use Lightning Design System docs."

source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_slds